# Qiskit textbook install error

Tags: qiskit, programming

I'm trying to install the `qiskit_textbook` repository (https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook) and I keep getting this error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/mb/sbqp79dx7zj7jpd6mfc1vdbh0000gn/T/pip-req-build-gqjhv69q/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/mb/sbqp79dx7zj7jpd6mfc1vdbh0000gn/T/pip-req-build-gqjhv69q/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/mb/sbqp79dx7zj7jpd6mfc1vdbh0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-wn16yzlv
         cwd: /private/var/folders/mb/sbqp79dx7zj7jpd6mfc1vdbh0000gn/T/pip-req-build-gqjhv69q/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/mb/sbqp79dx7zj7jpd6mfc1vdbh0000gn/T/pip-req-build-gqjhv69q/setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to install the `qiskit_textbook` repository? You should install Qiskit (https://qiskit.org/documentation/install.html) and Jupyter notebook, unless you have installed them already. Then you will be able open the `ipynb` files in the textbook repository.

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to call this: 

from qiskit_textbook.tools import array_to_latex

array_to_latex(final_state, pretext="\\text{Statevector} = ")

Comment: I see, sorry about that.

Comment: Many suggests that such issue might happen if your pip is not upgraded. But I am not so sure. May be if you 'Check the logs for full command output', - it may have more directions.